# Cannot disable remote Spring Boot JMX access

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmx, spring-boot-actuator

We have a Spring Boot application with actuator. We're trying to disable remote JMX access, but somehow this is not working. We've tried the following settings:

In Tomcat startup options:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=....../jmxremote.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true 
-Djava.security.manager 
-Djava.security.policy=jmx.policy
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=....jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=****
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=.....jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=****
```

In application.properties:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.datasource.jmx-enabled=false
endpoints.jmx.enabled=false
spring.jmx.server=localhost
```

However, we are still able to access JMX from a remote system. The only difference that the option `spring.jmx.enabled` makes is that Spring-specific MBeans are not available, but other MBeans are still available.

How can we disable remote access to JMX? Ideally we'd still like access when connecting from the local machine, but if necessary this might also be disabled.

ADDED
build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.16.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply from: "../dependencies.gradle"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    providedRuntime project(':....')
    compile project(':...')
    compile project(':...')
    compile project(':...')
    compile project(':...')

    compile group: 'com.hazelcast', name: 'hazelcast', version: '3.12'
    compile group: 'com.hazelcast', name: 'hazelcast-client', version: '3.12'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.11.Final'
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.2'

    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.0.1'

    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.2'

    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.9.5'
}
```

Comment: What if you remove all the startup options?

Comment: That's how we started of course. Result: remote JMX possible (unauthenticated). After that, we started experimenting with properties and startup-options, unsuccessfully until now.

Comment: I can't see that JMX remote is starting when nothing is configured. On which port can you access JMX remotely?

Comment: JMX is available on port 1099

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. How does your Maven or Gradle file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the exact same issue and solved it by using these settings:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=localhost
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=<path to jmxremote.password>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=<path to jmxremote.access>
```

Please note that order and explicitly setting properties to their default values *may* be necessary even though it obviously shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Diederik's solution, two properties needed to change

1. Set authenticate to true. And also specify password.file and access.file.
2. Set host to localhost or 127.0.0.1.

If authenticate is false or host is not localhost, remote access will be enabled.

Here is one sample

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=localhost \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=<path to password file> \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=<path to access file> \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
```